# Should you say al netilat yadaim if you're not sure how much bread you will be eating?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, bread

http://www.berachot.org/Q+A/q9.html:

> According to Sephardim, if one ate less than a kezayit of bread
>   there's no obligation to wash, if one ate one kezayit one should wash
>   without a Bracha of Al Netilat Yadayim and if one ate a Kebaytzah (2
>   Kezaytim) one should wash with a Bracha. (S"A 158:2, Yalkut Yosef
>   158:4). According to Ashkenazim preferably one should have a Kebaytzah
>   to wash with a Bracha but if one needs to have a kezayit one should
>   wash with a Bracha. If one eats less than a kezayit one should wash
>   without a Bracha. (Vezot HaBracha chap 2, pg 13 based on Igrot Moshe
>   4:44 and Rav Elyashiv)

If one is about to commence a meal with bread and is not sure how much bread will be eaten should one skip the brach al netilat yadayim? Or is the additional food counted towards the kebeya?

Comment: Why would you'd assume ספק ברכות להקל not apply

Comment: The last sentence would remove the ספק.