# Does other food combine to a c'beitza for the bracha of netilas yadayim?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements, netilat-yadayim-washing, matzah

It's a well known halacha that if one intends to eat less than a k'zais of bread then one doesn't make a bracha on al netilas yadayim.

This comes up sometimes on Pesach when there's not enough Matzah to give everyone a whole Matzah (which I presume is a k'beitza since I think a k'zais is about a half of a matzah and a k'beitza is twice that). Does other food combine to the k'beitza or does it have to be a full k'beitza of bread / matzah?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59416 possible duplicate